# Padding a comment with spaces

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, regex

Currently, the 15 char minimum on comments can be defeated by padding out the middle with spaces.

Fix:

```
s/\s+/ /
```

HTML ignores extra spaces anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got sick of the umpteen bajillion "bugs" opened on this, so we "fixed the bug".

Enjoy.

Comment: OMG, no! ____________________________________

Answer (score 20):

Why bother.  If folks are prepared to game the system with spaces to get a short comment in, they won't be fussed using other characters

```
Get it????????????????????????????????????????????????
No....................................................
Why not? ____________________________________________
```

This will lead to some really nasty visual comment hacks that make the cure worse than the disease.

Comment: Lemme get this straight... it's a feature, not a bug?

Comment: The 15-character-minimum feature is *"good enough"* they way it is.  This is to encourage behavior, not enforce it.  While the limit can be effectively bypassed, which the OP and you (jokingly?) call a bug, the candidate cures are worse than the disease--additional complexity that still does not actually prevent someone for sneaking in a short comment.