# Add a comment behaviour in regards to minimum characters?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Padding a comment with spaces.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11731/padding-a-comment-with-spaces)

On Server Fault, I posted a comment and someone posted the comment "Classic!" so I was going to post a comment back "Yes It Is" but I got an error message * required - at least 15 characters. How did the other person get to enter an 8 character comment, is that based on a certain amount of rep?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/can-we-get-rid-of-the-threshold-of-15-chars-for-comments

Comment: Better dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11731/padding-a-comment-with-spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pad comments with certain unicode characters or just some whitespace.

That will cause the comment submit form to validate, but the whitespace gets trimmed when the comment is displayed.

If you use the unicode zero-width-space, it just takes up no space...but technically is the correct number of characters.

Comment: Like This!

Comment: It does make you wonder why SO didn't use JS to trim that whitespace off if they were concerned about the minimum 15 characters in the first place.

Comment: Jeff has stated (not verbatim) that they knew and didn't care about this particular workaround.