# A question with all spaces is still accepted, even though more than one space together in HTML is displayed as one space, making it under 15 chars

Tags: bug, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Padding a comment with spaces.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11731/padding-a-comment-with-spaces)

Comment: I saw the duplicate - it deals with comments, not answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got sick of the umpteen bajillion "bugs" opened on this, so we "fixed the bug".

Enjoy.

Comment: What? I can no longer post short comments! What have you done!

Comment: Still can post short comments Isaac, don't worry.