# 15-char comment minimum is exploitable around

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Padding a comment with spaces.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11731/padding-a-comment-with-spaces)
>   [Do away with minimum char limits on comments.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17183/do-away-with-minimum-char-limits-on-comments)

Suppose I put in the comment box, '+1' then 13 spaces. I now can add the comment(presuming other conditions permitting). It shows up as +1, with the trailing whitespace stripped.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17183/do-away-with-minimum-char-limits-on-comments which is itself a duplicate of others.

Comment: Also, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/can-we-get-rid-of-the-threshold-of-15-chars-for-comments is "status-declined".

Comment: Strictly speaking, those were requests for the limit's removal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got sick of the umpteen bajillion "bugs" opened on this, so we "fixed the bug".

Enjoy.

Comment: Yay?                                   damn

Comment: oh         rly?

Comment: Hm               d

Comment: Yes, really!!!!

Comment: Hmm ​​​​​​​​​​​​